# Merge two images in java

Tags: java, image-processing, java-2d

I have two images, one base image (background image) and the second is an overlay image. The base image is 180*269 pixels and the overlay image is `1000*2250` pixels.

I have to place the overlay image with specified points. This is almost like virtual dressing i.e you will have a model or girl image and you have to overlay a top or dress on her. We have captured shoulder, waist, hips and thighs x and y coordinates of both images.

example:
Base image - 87,213,244,217,90,435,236,436,82,352,228,352,94,515,230,525

Layered image - 150,111,235,111,149,220,230,223,157,174,227,173,153,265,218,266

Output images needs to be of base image dimensions.

Please help us to merge these images at specified points in Java 2D or `jai` library.
Give me any reference.

Answer (score 4):

See this tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html

Basically:

1. create a `BufferedImage`
2. call `createGraphics` on the image to create a `Graphics2D` object
3. call `drawImage` on the graphics object to draw the base image
4. call `drawImage` again with the overlay image.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. I have used this functionality. However i have to merge these images  with  coordinates given.

Comment: drawImage lets you specify a location to draw the image.